# Symfony 2.8 : composer install error

Tags: php, git, symfony, caching, composer-php

I clone a new git repo that contain symfony project , when I run composer install command I got this error :

> Cannot create cache directory
>   /home/sa7noun/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or
>   directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
>
> Cannot create cache directory /home/sa7noun/.composer/cache/files/, or
>   directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
>
> Composer could not find a composer.json file in
>   /home/sa7noun/Romain/Lefebvre
>
> To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as
>   described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

Comment: Please apply writable permission to cache directory.

Comment: Can the user you use to run "composer install" access `/home/sa7noun/`and create files/folders in it? That's what the error says it can't.

Comment: -add writable permission : sudo chmod -R 777 www/app/cache/
--> not working the same error appear.

Comment: @sahnoun apply writable permisison to directories that composer tries to create things in, such as : `/home/sa7noun/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/` + `/home/sa7noun/.composer/cache/` + `/home/sa7noun/.composer/cache/`. Finally are you sure you are in the right directory?

Comment: @smarber , composer install work perfectly because i was in the wrong directory you're right , but there is a problem the cache directory cannot be created   !

Comment: cache path : Lefbre/www/app/cache
 source code path : Lefbre/www/src..

Answer (score 0):

If on a linux/mac filesystem:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/sa7noun/.composer/cache
```